# Help with correct syntax regarding multisort please

Tags: filter, array, sort, multisort

Hi hoping for a quick resolution on this as a lot of scripting relies upon it. I have an array:

```
{% set furniture = [
     {
         'name': 'chair',
         'price': '100'
     },
     {
         'name': 'bench',
         'price': '500'
     }
   ]
%}
```

and I'm trying to sort it by price:

```
{% set sorted = furniture|multisort(['price'],['SORT_DESC'],['SORT_REGULAR']) %}
```

but all I get is this error:

array_multisort(): Argument #2 is expected to be an array or a sort flag.

I've also tried:

```
{% set rides = furniture|multisort(furniture['price'],['SORT_DESC'],['SORT_REGULAR']) %}
```

but then I get the error:

Key "price" for array with keys "0, 1" does not exist.

I've kind of run out of ideas as to how to tackle it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the quotes on 2nd/3rd arguments:

`{% set rides = furniture|multisort(furniture['price'],[SORT_DESC],[SORT_REGULAR]) %}`

Comment: Yes that worked although my syntax was wrong so this worked: {% set sorted = furniture|multisort(['price'],[SORT_ASC],[SORT_REGULAR]) %} Thanks very much for your help!!!!!